# ED50 in non linear logistic regression in R

Tags: nonlinear-regression, nls, dose-response, lorenz-curve

I am new to R and I want to find the **ED50** with its confidence interval in the **drc** package in R. I found the best model is **lorentz.4** according to AIC. But I get a warning message for the confidence interval, plus during the summary.

Warning message: In sqrt(diag(varMat)) : NaNs produced

Error in ED.drc(mod.drc, c(10, 50, 90)) : ED values cannot be calculated

Any help is so appreciated. Thank you. Here is the code:

```
**library(devtools)
install_github("onofriandreapg/aomisc")
library(aomisc)
library(drc) 
X <- c(25, 50, 100, 200, 300)
Y1 <- c(0.12, 0.14,0.44, 0.14, 0.07)
mod.drc <- drm(Y1 ~ X, fct =DRC.lorentz.4() )
plot(mod.drc, ylim = c(0, 0.8), log = "") 
AIC(mod.drc)
summary(mod.drc)
confint(mod.drc)
ED(mod.drc, c(10, 50, 90))**
```

Comment: How can you hope to estimate an ED50 when you have never observed any values at or above that level??  It's even worse: apart from an unusually high response in the middle, your responses are *decreasing* with increasing dose!  Thus, any effort to extrapolate beyond your highest dose will be completely uncertain.

Comment: Thank you for your help.